# My ASReml GLMM is predicting "NA" values for one of my variables, any suggestions on how to fix this?

Tags: r, mixed-model, prediction, asreml

My question is: What is the relationship between malaria and schistosomiasis?

Therefor, I have plotted this GLMM;

`sch1 <- asreml(fixed = sqrt(Schisto.elisa) ~ Malaria.RDT+Vil+Age+
              wealth+water.score+Canoe+Bed.or.matress+
              what.is.bilharzia+what.is.malaria+Trad.med,
            random=~FID+spl(Age),
            family = asreml.gaussian(link = "identity"),
            na.method.Y = "exclude",
            na.method.X = "exclude", 
            data = dframe1)`

From this model, I have tried to predict Malaria, however, when I use the predict function ASReml produces NA values.

The predict code is:

`pred1 <- predict(sch1, classify = "Malaria.RDT:Vil:Age:wealth:water.score:Canoe:Bed.or.matress:what.is.bilharzia:what.is.malaria:Trad.med",
                    levels =list(Malaria.RDT = seq(1,4),
                                 Vil=c("BUGOTO"),
                                 Age=mean(dframe1$Age),
                                 wealth=mean(dframe1$wealth),
                                 water.score=mean(dframe1$water.score),
                                 Canoe=c("0"),
                                 Bed.or.matress=("1"),
                                 what.is.bilharzia=c("1"),
                                 what.is.malaria=c("1"),
                                 Trad.med=("1")))`

Obviously, I have validated my model e.t.c,  and my supervisor has suggested that the problem is due to over specification of my model. I am not sure what this means, and Ideally just need to fix this problem.